# Java to scala converter

Tags: java, scala

I ran a converter I found...
http://javatoscala.com/

On some java code, it seemed to do okay, but running this scala code (through spark-submit) it complains on not being able to find SortedMap (I have the imports) and does not find the defined classes I made as well (like in example code before DateLayerData(), though this is most likely due to the errors with SortedMap within it)

```
 import org.neo4j.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

import java.util.Map


import java.util.SortedMap
import java.util.TreeMap
//remove if not needed
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._


    val conf = new SparkConf.setMaster("local").setAppName("neo4jspark")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)   
    val neo = Neo4j(sc)





class DateLayerData {

  var fromDate: String = _
  var toDate: String = _
  var fromBird: String = _
  var toBird: String = _
  var ptCntBbox: java.lang.Integer = _
  var arrCntBbox: java.lang.Integer = _
  var depCntBbox: java.lang.Integer = _
  var areaBbox: java.lang.Long = _
  var strengthBbox: java.lang.Double = _
  var radiusPointData: SortedMap[Long, DateRadiusData] = new TreeMap()


}




   <console>:44: error: not found: value SparkConf
           val conf = new SparkConf.setMaster("local").setAppName("neo4jspark")
                          ^
<console>:44: error: not found: value conf
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
                                  ^
neo: org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j = org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j@6fc84468
<console>:22: error: not found: type SortedMap
         var radiusPointData: SortedMap[Long, DateRadiusData] = new TreeMap()
                              ^
<console>:22: error: not found: type TreeMap
         var radiusPointData: SortedMap[Long, DateRadiusData] = new TreeMap()
                                                                    ^

Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_91)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, I know, but why not use the Java Spark API?

Comment: This compiles fine for me.  Perhaps a clean build is all you need?

Comment: Not using java spark API because on reddit and other places people commented it was cumbersome, and so I figured bite bullet now and just do it in scala (which most examples online are there).  I am very new to Spark and struggling just to get things working.   As to it compiling fine, I wonder if it is my setup of the .scala file in general (I am still learning how to define and call classes within a file etc).

Comment: updated question with the full code and output of the simplest test with error.  Not sure how to do a clean build when running code like this:  `spark-shell --conf spark.neo4j.bolt.password=TestNeo4j --packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:2.0.0-M2,graphframes:graphframes:0.2.0-spark2.0-s_2.11 -i neo4jJavaConvertTest.scala`

Comment: You are missing parenthesis after the SparkConf, should be `new SparkConf()`.  Could you also try prefixing your Map types so use `util.SortedMap` and `util.TreeMap` to make sure it's not a problem of the names being confused with the scala collections of the same name.  Finally, try creating an object with a main method and putting your code into the main instead of having it just float out there, then try to compile it instead of trying to interpret it with spark-shell.  Spark-shell already creates the `SparkContext` for you so trying to create it again may be a source of trouble.

Comment: I would also try removing the `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._` import.  Java conversions is a dangerous import which can lead to unexpected behavior and shouldn't be used as it tried to automatically convert your collectionsas it sees fit.  If you need to convert between Java and Scala collection use `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._` which is much friendlier as it requires you to be explicit about when you want to convert.

Comment: This seems like a remarkably bad idea. You wouldn't be able to use scala api if you are going to write code in java, even if you plan to convert it to java later, so ... what's the point???

Comment: I prefixed the map with util.SortedMap it still isn't finding something as I am getting the TreeMap is not a member of package util and SortedMap is not a member of package Util.    The parenthesis worked, and I did remove the `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._`

Comment: @Dima I did not write the original code, it is a java program computing on large amounts of data, that I am hoping to get running in Spark with the shortest path possible to a working example.  This is the best path forward i can see.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it to me at all :/ Either stick with java api, or write spark code in scala, and just call your java code from it.

Comment: @Dima is there examples of calling Java from scala ?   If I could not convert some of these java classes to Scala that would be saving me some time. I really need to just rewrite one function (that does the calculation and the calls to a neo4j database) in Spark in hopes of speeding up the process.

Comment: I am not sure about "examples". You can call java from scala the same way you would call it from java ... or the same way you call scala from scala. Just make sure you are not mixing scala types with java (some have the same names, but are very different things - like `Int` and `java.lang.Int` - so, make sure you are using the correct package).